# C# - Pass data to JS and wait result to process

Tags: c#, ajax, multithreading, asynchronous

Is there anyway to pass something from C# to JS, then do something in JS and give it back to the C# code?

I'm working on MVC and I'm trying to encrypt the password in the view, before sending, so no one can peek. My idea was:

1. When hitting submit, an AJAX call ask to the server the generation of a new RSA key pair
2. The server generates the new key pair and sends the public key to the client, waiting for a response
3. The client recieves the public key, encrypts in the js file the password and sends the encrypted password to the server
4. The server recieves the data it was waiting for and decrypts the password

I think is the "best" way to do it, but I don't know if it's possible to start a thread with Ajax and then keep it waiting until it recieves a response, or dies after x amount of time. And I think that's the best way because it will generate an unique key pair each time that you need to submit the password and will never be stored, so if someone picks at the request you sent, they'll get an encrypted password that can't be used for nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is malformed. You do not want to server send anything to client, but client sending something to server.
Like your scenario, which seems good:

1. Client asks Server: Give me Public Key
2. Server responds: Here's the key and ID you need for me to be able to select private key
3. Client encrypts, Server doesn't care what is happening here.
4. Client sends to server: Here's encrypted password and ID you gave me before.
5. Server looks up its key cache for given key ID
6. Server decrypts the password using private key retrieved from cache and Client waits for response.
7. Server responds: Password is OK or Password is wrong OR if couldn't find provided ID should return some timeout or other error.

Of course if you'd like to generate RSA keys on the fly, randomly for every request you'd need to hold somewhere the key to decrypt and some session key (which would Client know too), so you could match them up, but it should work.

Built-in .NET Memory Cache seems perfectly designed for this task. You can put data in the cache, retrieve it, remove it and set up validity time, after which .NET manages itself to remove object from the cache.
Please refer to .NET documentation available: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx in this matter.

It is possible to create request in Ajax and make it wait for completion or timeout, but you must keep in mind, that server is unable to contact the client, unless client is asking for contact (sending request) or you are using websockets (which, I think, are like cannon to kill a fly, for this task).

Comment: Sorry, what I mean when I say that is that the response in step 2, has to keep waiting for step four, if the server sends a "return publicKey;" then when I reach again with the encrypted password the private key will be different ergo my encrypted key will be obsolete. If this is not clear, pleas tell me and I'll elaborate a bit more. Thanks anyway for the answer

Comment: That's why I mentioned session key.

Just return session key / RSA ID or anything with RSA Public Key and on the server side cache public key for your timeout time.
Then client would just need to return RSA ID with encrypted password, so server can get private key from key cache. You can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx to hold private keys and manage timeouts.

Look up my edited version of the flow.